# Any browser that can let a user switch between Google or Yahoo or Facebook accounts quickly?

Tags: browser, user-profiles

Let's say we keep one gmail account for work and one for private emails.

Or one Facebook account for our personal use and another one for trying different apps.

We can open two browsers and then sign into different accounts that way, but doing so may mean installing and maintaining 2, 3 or more different browsers.

Would there be a browser that can let user switch between profile easily?  Then there will be no need for separate browsers and this way, we can have 3 profiles all on 1 browser, instead of installing and maintaining 3 different browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox supports [Profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles), also there's [CookieSwap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3255) extension that makes it possible to use different accounts with a single profile (though not a the same time).

Answer (score 4):

With Internet Explorer 8 there is a "New Session" menu item which opens a new window with a different session. You can log into another account there without those two interfering with each other. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx) blog post talks a little more about this.

Answer (score 2):

Launch Firefox with the -profilemanager option, then you can create additional profiles you can use with the -p "profilename" command line switch (you could make a shortcut). You couldn't use them in the same window, but you could use them simultaniously. You could install an extension to change the window title to differentiate them more easily.

Comment: thanks.  will it be 1 instance of Firefox and 3 different Windows?  Or 3 instances of Firefox?

Comment: I believe 3 instances, unfortunately, but I could be wrong!

Comment: Thee instances. And this might be the one single useful use case for Firefox's dreaded profiles. Most of the time they are just in the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question (regarding Chrome), the answer to which is to use multiple profiles. See this for details: [Is it possible to have a Google Chrome shortcut use a different user agent than an existing Chrome window?](https://superuser.com/questions/8708/is-it-possible-to-have-a-google-chrome-application-shortcut-use-a-different-user)

Answer (score 0):

"Incognito Browsing" will handle this, too.

I use it to keep my facebook session open along with my fiancee's :)